# Proguard removes META-INF/versions/9 code

Tags: java, javafx, proguard, obfuscation, java-9

I'm making JavaFX app and I'm obfuscating it with proguard. One of the libraries I'm using, has some Java9 specific classes in META-INF but proguard does not copy those classes from the injar to the obfuscated one and app crashes at runtime. Any special rules I can add to proguard to prevent this?

Comment: See this [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/671/).